# Unknown column in 'field list' while executing seeder command

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, migration

I have created migration file and its seeder file for the table. Now when I try to execute the seeder command it is throwing error of `"Unknown column in 'field list'"`

I have recreated these many times, I don't know why I am getting this! May be some minor mistake I have made.

Here is my migration file:

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('subscriptions', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      subscriptionPlanType: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      memberCount: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      amount: {
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('subscriptions');
  }
};
```

and here is the seeder file:

```
"use strict";

/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /**
     * Add seed commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.bulkInsert('People', [{
     *   name: 'John Doe',
     *   isBetaMember: false
     * }], {});
     */
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert("Users", [
      {
        subscriptionPlanType: "Monthly",
        name: "Tset1",
        memberCount: 15,
        amount: 65.99,
        createdAt: "Oct 17 2022 22:34:39",
        updatedAt: "Oct 17 2022 22:34:39",
      },
      {
        subscriptionPlanType: "Yearly",
        name: "Test2",
        memberCount: 25,
        amount: 105.99,
        createdAt: "Oct 17 2022 22:34:39",
        updatedAt: "Oct 17 2022 22:34:39",
      },
    ]);
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /**
     * Add commands to revert seed here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.bulkDelete('People', null, {});
     */
  },
};
```

And I am getting the error while executing this command: `npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all`

> Unknown column 'subscriptionPlanType' in 'field list'

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake either in the migration or in the seeder. The table names are not the same. In the migrations, the table name is `subscriptions` and in the seeder it is `Users`

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you @Joe.

Comment: Top. Don't forget to mark the forum as solved for others. Good luck Jayna ;)